# redhat subscription server

Tags: linux

i want to have a RH subscription server which is able to access the redhat portal and all other server should be able to access this RH subscription server.
so all other server will be offline and only redhat server will be online which is able to connect to redhat portal. 
i am trying to find since morning but cant find any guide - is possible? a proper guide which allow me to configure both subscription and client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_satellite/6.2/html/installation_guide/what_satellite_server_and_capsule_server_do) of RedHat Satellite which can do what you want. But I am afraid you should have subscription for this software (Subscription for RHEL is not enough). Also you need to have subscription for every server "behind" the Satellite.

> Red Hat Satellite is a system management solution that enables you to
>   deploy, configure, and maintain your systems across physical, virtual,
>   and cloud environments. Satellite provides provisioning, remote
>   management and monitoring of multiple Red Hat Enterprise Linux
>   deployments with a single, centralized tool. Red Hat Satellite Server
>   synchronizes the content from Red Hat Customer Portal, and provides
>   functionality including fine-grained life cycle management, user and
>   group role-based access control, integrated subscription management,
>   as well as advanced GUI, CLI, and API access.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks a lot - so without satellite it is not possible to have a only subscription server  ?   i dont have satellite server yet .. actually i dont have more than 5 RH server so it is useless for me to have satellite server ... how much it (satellite server )cost?

Comment: @Dion0009, I have no idea. You should better contact RH representatives. I saw something like 5k USD for 50 or less servers. But my personal opinion is for 5 servers this software will not payback